# How to filter and remove some node in an xml file using sxlt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml file:

```
<A>
<B>
    <elt>Add</elt>
    ...there are some element here
    <bId>2</bId>
</B>
<B>
    <elt>Add</elt>
    ...there are some element here
    <bId>2</bId>
</B>
<B>
    <elt>Add</elt>
    ...there are some element here
    <bId>2</bId>
</B>
<B>
    <elt>can</elt>
    ...there are some element here
    <bId>3</bId>
</B>
<B>
    <elt>can</elt>
    ...there are some element here
    <bId>3</bId>
</B>
```

I want to check the value of each **bId** element. If this value is the same with the preceding or following **bId** element, then I will put the other elements of the bloc **B** in another bloc excepted the element **bId** which will be rejected after the transformation. To make my question understanding by you, here is the expected output:

```
<CA>
  <cplx>
    <spRule>
            <elt>Add</elt>
             ...
    </spRule>
    <spRule>
            <elt>Add</elt>
             ...
    </spRule>
    <spRule>
            <elt>Add</elt>
            ...
    </spRule>
  </cplx>
  <cplx>
    <spRule>
            <elt>can</elt>
            ...
    </spRule>
    <spRule>
            <elt>can</elt>
            ...
    </spRule>
  </cplx>
</CA>
```

Even though when the element in the xml file are not sorted by the value of **bId**, I want also get the same expected output.
I try to use this xsl code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="bId"
  <CA>
    <cplx>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="node()[preceding::bId]">
         <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
    </cplx>
  </CA>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it doesn't walk. Could someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on "when the element in the xml file are not sorted by the value of bId, I want also get the same expected output", that sounds as if you simply want to group all elements with a certain `bId` value, while your previous description "If this value is the same with the preceding or following" sounds like a different requirement, namely to group only adjacent elements.

Comment: Hello Martin. I really want to group all elements with the same value of **bId** even thoug if these are not sorted. For example, we have in our xml these value of **bId**: 2, 2, 3, 2, 2... Then I will group first all elements with the value of **bId** =2 together and the rest in another bloc.

Comment: See the second sample in my answer, you simply want to group then, which is done with http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first description to group adjacent elements with the same `bId` value is what you want an XSLT 1.0 way is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1"
    match="B[bId = preceding-sibling::B[1]/bId]"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::B[not(bId = preceding-sibling::B[1]/bId)][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <CA>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="B[not(preceding-sibling::B[1]) or not(bId = preceding-sibling::B[1]/bId)]"/>
    </CA>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <cplx>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=". | key('k1', generate-id())" mode="sp"/>
    </cplx>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B" mode="sp">
    <spRule>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::bId)]"/>
    </spRule>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you simply want to group all `B` elements with the same `bId` value then use

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1"
    match="B"
    use="bId"/>

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <CA>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="B[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', bId)[1])]"/>
    </CA>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B">
    <cplx>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', bId)" mode="sp"/>
    </cplx>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="B" mode="sp">
    <spRule>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::bId)]"/>
    </spRule>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @ Martin. Thanks a lot for your help. The first sample is functionning very well and it does what I wanted.
I tried to use the 2nd sample, but it doesn't walk. I get this as result: `<CA>
   <cplx/>
   <cplx/>
</CA>
`
I don't know what is wrong with this sample. Note that, the result is obtained by applying the xslt file on the xml file give above.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected a mistake in the second sample, it should work now and be more efficient and easier to understand and maintain than the first (which needs complicated expressions to do the adjacente grouping in XSLT 1.0).

Comment: All is ok now Martin. Thanks again.